# How to use DataSource in not injectable files in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

NestJS is now using the new typeorm version that introduced the DataSource.

How can I access the DataSource in a non inject way? for example, with the deprecated function getManager() you could create a query builder in any file.

How would you access the data source manager now?

Comment: What's the use case you're trying to fulfill here?

Comment: Some queries are reusable and independent of any service, we have implemented them in a "queries" file. With the deprecated getManager() we could do it easily

Comment: You could pass the connection to a method that then does these queries.